# Selenium test on a GWT app - request not sent to server

Tags: gwt, selenium

I'm writing a selenium test for a GWT app.  It uses the mouseover/
mousedown/mouseup approach to click pushbuttons.  It clicks the Login
button of my app, which calls up the div containing userid and
password entry fields, and that works just fine.  It then enters a userid and
password, then clicks the Submit button for the login form.

If I run it slowly, I can see the button click, but the request never
gets sent to the server (I'm watching the wire).

In fact, if, while the selenium IDE is still open, I manually click
the button, the request is not sent.  If I then close the selenium IDE
and click the button, the request goes through fine.

Anybody seen this one?  It seems really strange.

Update:

Firebug shows a script error.  Apparently, the selenium script has some conflict with the GWT script.  Here's the beginning of the error, but the whole thing is quite lengthy:

[Exception... "'com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): result is null fileName: chrome://selenium-ide/content/recorder.js lineNumber: 74 stack: ([object XMLHttpRequest],"POST","http://localhost:8080/login",true)@chrome://selenium-ide/content/recorder.js:74 XPC_SJOW_CallWrapper((function (url, windowName, windowFeatures, replaceFlag) {if (self.openCalled) {return self.originalOpen.call(window, url, windowName, windowFeatures, replaceFlag);} else {self.o

Comment: what version of GWT are you running, there were some known issues with Selenium in older versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer.  It's a little embarrassing, but it provides the answer and it's funny, too.  I'll share the answer so that you can avoid the problem, and perhaps have a laugh at my expense.  :)

The answer is that you have to compile to OBF instead of PRETTY.  All the associated links are listed below.  They fully explain the problem, and how to avoid it.

What's funny about this?  Well, as I was going through search, I finally hit upon the first link below.  Almost immediately, I realized, or at least had a sneaking suspicion, that I had solved this problem before.  Sure enough, the original question was posted in October, and I was the poster.  So, I got an answer before, and completely forgot.  Ah, well.  Hope the answer helps someone, and my comic misfortune brightens your day.

http://clearspace.openqa.org/message/50170

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5d6a9c448a82b916/af62e5877237b107?lnk=raot

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2861

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try clickAt or mouseDownAt, they seem to perform a bit differently.

Comment: It's not an issue of the button being clicked.  It is being clicked, and I know that part is working.  It's a failure of the underlying ajax call.

Comment: Cool.  It's a tricky one.  If I figure it out, I'll post an update.